# How to Construct a vector of Tuples and Sort them like Pair?

Tags: c++, sorting, tuples

Suppose, I have several integer elements like this:

`(3 9 1), (1 5 2), (2 8 3), (1 4 4), (1 6 5), (1 5 6)`

Now I want to sort the elements like vector of pairs are sorted. Only difference is that instead of 2 keys we have 3 keys here. After sorting the elements will look like:

`(1 4 4), (1 5 2), (1 5 6), (1 6 5), (2 8 3), (3 9 1)`

Is there any STL or other techniques to achieve this? I found out about `Tuples` but having some problems to understand this well.
 Can you guys help me in any way please? May be by providing useful links or Explaining the process.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp you can just use std::sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `vector` of `tuple` can be sorted using nothing but STL if you want.

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    std::vector< std::tuple<int, int, int> > myVec;

    myVec.emplace_back(3, 9, 1);
    myVec.emplace_back(1, 5, 2);
    myVec.emplace_back(2, 8, 3);
    myVec.emplace_back(1, 4, 4);
    myVec.emplace_back(1, 6, 5);
    myVec.emplace_back(1, 5, 6);

    std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());

    for (auto i : myVec){
        std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ", " << std::get<1>(i) << ", " << std::get<2>(i) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the example from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) just modified with your values.

How it works is a new `tuple` is constructed with `emplace_back` and added to the end of the vector.  You could use `push_back(std::make_tuple(...` if you want but that seems overly complicated.  Then you `sort` the `vector` as you would any other `vector`.  The default behavior of `sort` is ascending.  You can change the behavior of `sort` by adding you own `comp`.  The arguments of your comparing function will be 2 `tuple`s.  The return type is the boolean result of your comparison.  Since `tuple`s have all the comparisons (`<`,`>`, `<=`,etc) already, you don't need to redefine them.  You can use this to compare dissimilar things as well, it just gets more complicated.

```
bool myFunction(const std::tuple<int, int, int> &i, const std::tuple<int, int, int> &j) {
    return i > j;
}

....
std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), myFunction);
....
```

And this will sort the vector in descending order.  You can replace `myFunction` with a lambda as well.

```
std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [](const std::tuple<int, int, int> &i, const std::tuple<int, int, int> &j) {
    return i > j;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose two solutions: the first using a custom structure using a custom `<` operator that uses [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to compare the three integers in order, and the second using [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct three_integers {
  int a, b, c;
  bool operator<(const three_integers &other) const {
    return std::tie(a, b, c) < std::tie(other.a, other.b, other.c);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // 1st solution using a custom structure
  // std::set containers are always ordered according to the < operator
  std::set<three_integers> sorted_set = {{3, 9, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {2, 8, 3},
                                         {1, 4, 4}, {1, 6, 5}, {1, 5, 6}};

  std::cout << "Sorted set:\n";
  for (auto &element : sorted_set) {
    std::cout << "(" << element.a << " " << element.b << " " << element.c << ")"
              << std::endl;
  }

  std::vector<three_integers> sorted_vector = {{3, 9, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {2, 8, 3},
                                               {1, 4, 4}, {1, 6, 5}, {1, 5, 6}};

  // std::vector is not ordered, so we call std::sort on it to make it just like
  // std::set, it will use our custom < operator
  std::sort(sorted_vector.begin(), sorted_vector.end());

  std::cout << "Sorted vector:\n";
  for (auto &element : sorted_vector) {
    std::cout << "(" << element.a << " " << element.b << " " << element.c << ")"
              << std::endl;
  }

  // 2nd solution using tuples
  std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> sorted_vector_tuple = {
      {3, 9, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {2, 8, 3}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 6, 5}, {1, 5, 6}};

  std::sort(sorted_vector_tuple.begin(), sorted_vector_tuple.end());

  std::cout << "Sorted vector of tuples:\n";
  for (auto &element : sorted_vector_tuple) {
    std::cout << "(" << std::get<0>(element) << " " << std::get<1>(element)
              << " " << std::get<2>(element) << ")" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Sorted set:
(1 4 4)
(1 5 2)
(1 5 6)
(1 6 5)
(2 8 3)
(3 9 1)
Sorted vector:
(1 4 4)
(1 5 2)
(1 5 6)
(1 6 5)
(2 8 3)
(3 9 1)
Sorted vector of tuples:
(1 4 4)
(1 5 2)
(1 5 6)
(1 6 5)
(2 8 3)
(3 9 1)
```

I recommend you to read the [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) documentation.